# Recognize multiple grammar choices

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, grammar

I have this code to set up a custom grammar and load it into a speech recognition engine

```
DictationGrammar customDictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
customDictationGrammar.Name = "Dictation";
customDictationGrammar.Enabled = true;
GrammarBuilder grammar = new GrammarBuilder();
grammar.Append(new Choices("turn", "on", "off",  "lamp"));
grammar.Culture = ri.Culture;
Grammar g = new Grammar(grammar);



spRecEng.LoadGrammar(g);
spRecEng.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(spRecEng_SpeechRecognized);
spRecEng.SpeechRecognitionRejected += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(spRecEng_SpeechRecognitionRejected);

spRecEng.SetInputToAudioStream(source.Start(), new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 16000, 16, 1, 32000, 2, null));
spRecEng.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Is it possible to make it so it will recognize multiple options e.g. `turn`, `on`, and `lamp` or would I have to write in all variations I could say it in my Choices array?

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with `customDictationGrammar`, just creates an object and throws it away?

Comment: Also, this example shows how to put together word order: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd split your grammar into multiple parts - a state (on/off), a noun (lamp), and a verb (turn).  As your grammar expands (I'm pretty sure you're going to want to turn other things on besides the lamp), you can easily update your program.  (Also, this makes it easy to bind [SemanticResultKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.semanticresultkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the various parts and [SemanticResultValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576586%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the various options in the parts, so you don't have to parse English text.)

```
GrammarBuilder state = new GrammarBuilder();
state.Append(new Choices("on", "off"));
state.Culture = ri.Culture;
GrammarBuilder noun = new GrammarBuilder();
noun.Append(new Choices("lamp"));
noun.Culture = ri.Culture;
GrammarBuilder verb = new GrammarBuilder();
verb.Append(new Choices("turn"));
verb.Culture = ri.Culture;   

GrammarBuilder grammar = new GrammarBuilder();
grammar.Append(verb);
grammar.Append(lamp);
grammar.Append(state);
Grammar g = new Grammar(grammar);
```

If you *really* wanted users to say "off lamp turn" or any other word order, then you can still separate the parts, but combine them using a `Choices` element, and use the [repeat count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576577%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to enforce a minimum count:

```
GrammarBuilder grammar = new GrammarBuilder();
Choices c = new Choices([verb, lamp, state]);
grammar.Append(c, 2, 3);
Grammar g = new Grammar(grammar);
```